# Can I get the data of those whom I am not following on twitter?

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

I seem to be having problems with this in the twitter API.

I want the global data from the API which includes :
1. All those posts from the users I am following.
2. All those posts from the users I am not following.

Is this possible with the twitter API ? Has anyone tried it before ?

I'm using python, but any type of answer would be helpful.

Comment: Could you give your relevant code ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.
What you can do is say create a list of customers(those whom you follow) in a database...now check for each tweet if it from your customer then pass if not then do as desired.

Comment: Umm, I actually don't follow anyone yet ! Is there a way without using people I follow ? Because automating followers of followers or maybe more might take long.

Answer (score 0):

if you can get data of those whom you are following then you can also get data of those whom you are not following

Comment: How ? I mean, have you tried it or are you logically implying it ? If you are, then please tell me how